# Best array for this case

Tags: java, arrays

I have one problem of choosing which array use for this case. There are many arrays like list, colection, and others. I want to keep two numbers like this in array(numbers here is random): 
(many rows and 2 columns).

```
2, 4
4, 8
8, 7
...
```

But also have functionality with this array, easily take first array row and put it at the end. What can you suggest for me to use in this case?

p.s. im new so I want pick best option, thats why im here.

Comment: You're asking about data structures in general; arrays are just one specific kind of structure. What are you using it for?

Comment: There is only one array - the array. All other "arrays" that you mentioned are called "collections".

Comment: For your particular case try using HashMaps. :)

Comment: you can work with an array in lists like `List<int[]> arr` because you know that the first dimension is a fixed value (ie 2). The list will give you a variable 2nd dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by saying *easily*. Easy for programming or high performance.
Since you are new, I guess you are looking for the first one. I would stick with an `ArrayList<Integer>` or an `ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>`, where Pair is a custom class like this:

```
public class Pair<A, B>
{
    public Pair(A a, B b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
    public A a;
    public B b;
}
```

Then use like this:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>();
list.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(3, 5));
list.add(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(7, 1));
// now take the first and put it at the end:
list.add(list.remove(0));
```

---

Edit: If performance of moving the first element to the end is the bottleneck and you want this to go fast, well, then use a LinkedList. This will be an O(1) operation, whereas doing it with an ArrayList, it will be a O(n) operation.

Answer (score 3):

You should better create a class, say, `Pair`:

```
class Pair {
    private int i1;
    private int i2;

    public Pair(int i1, int i2) { this.i1 = i1; this.i2 = i2;  }

    public int getI1() { return i1; }

    public int getI2() { return i2; }
}
```

And then choose between `ArrayList<Pair>`, `HashSet<Pair>`, etc. depending on you particular needs.

Comment: hmm I have made something similar earlier with other class maybe its will work thanks i will try

Comment: +1: In fact I like the non-generics version, because the JVM would continuously box and unbox.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are talking about collections, not arrays: array is one specific kind of collection, and the most primitive one at that. You should use arrays directly when the number of elements in a collection is known at the time the collection is created, and never changes after that.

If your requirement is to remove an element from the beginning of a collection and inserting it at the end, then you should either use a [`Queue<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) or a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), and make an object that represents the pair of numbers its generic type argument. These data structures are optimized for quick insertion and removal from the ends.